# How do I use Google Doc to Get real time Quotes?

Tags: google-sheets, finance

So I have been trying built a spreadsheet which tracks multiple Stocks or Bonds , and one I am trying to add is the US 10-year Treasury .

the formula I used is
=importXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/bond/tmubmusd10y?countrycode=bx","/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/h3/bg-quote")

and it keep showing Imported Content is Empty as I am trying to the get the % Yield

I tried some other sites, unfortunately, it seems like this error is very persistent.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//h1[@class='company__name']")
```

[image]

---

update:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(B14, "//h3[@class='intraday__price sup--right']"),,2)&"%"
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the Confusion , I forgot to add this to the question . I was trying to get the %Yield

Comment: It seems like you didn't just copy the XML and pasted it , how did you do it ?

Comment: @user16445499 I just copy-pasted it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SymEv.png